# Anime where the a vampire(girl) awaits the reincarnation of her lover

Tags: story-identification, anime

Few years back, I remember watching an anime where a girls lover was killed before her. She was a vampire and she waited hundreds/thousand years for her lovers return. The character art is distinguishably different from the other animes and the story was full of gore violence. I have been looking for it ever since. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: May want to ask on the AnimeSE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bet it was Kurozuka (2008)
[Anidb entry](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=6098)
[Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurozuka)

> The series begins in 12th century Japan and centers on Kuro, a character based loosely on the legendary Japanese swordsman Minamoto no Yoshitsune. Kuro and his servant, Benkei, meet a beautiful and mysterious woman named Kuromitsu while on the run from Kuro's elder brother, who seeks his life. Kuromitsu and Kuro fall in love, but he soon discovers that she harbors a terrible secret: she is a vampiric immortal. Following an attack by his pursuers, Kuro is badly injured and must imbibe Kuromitsu's blood to save his own life. Kuro is then betrayed and attacked by Benkei, who has been subverted by a shadowy organization called the Red Army, and Kuro's head is severed, which interferes with his transformation into a fully immortal being.
>
> Kuro loses consciousness and wakes up centuries later in a post-apocalyptic, dystopian Japan. The surviving citizens have fallen under constant oppression by the Red Army, and Kuro is quickly found and recruited by an underground revolutionary movement called Haniwa. The remaining episodes follow Kuro's fight with the Red Army and its host of elite warriors, who have been enhanced by samples of Kuromitsu's blood, and his quest to find his inexplicably lost love.

Comment: I'm not certain if this is a good match, but I added some of the description from Wikipedia in hopes that it might spark some recognition in the querent.

Comment: Spot on! So many thanks! I guess this is a question more appropriate for AnimeSE so I'll probably move my ass over there :)